# Docker build cmake multiple containers with same custom library

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, docker-compose, shared-libraries

I'll start off by saying that I'm new to Docker and a novice with cmake so forgive any ignorance.  I'm working on porting a series of applications and a single shared library to a docker environment.  From my understanding Docker does not play well with shared libraries so I'd need to static link.  My goal is to use docker-compose to build multiple different application containers but each of these containers using the same custom library (that was setup as a .so in previous environment).  I'm currently setup to do cross-compile w/ Docker and can build and run each app w/o the library.  Now I need to add in the library.

Current folder/file setup is as follows:

```
app1:
  inc:
    app1.h <--includes mysharedlib.h
  src:
    app1.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
  custom-toolchain.cmake
  Dockerfile

app2:
  inc:
    app2.h <--includes mysharedlib.h
  src:
    app2.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
  custom-toolchain.cmake
  Dockerfile

MySharedLib:
  inc:
    mysharedlib.h
  src:
    mysharedlib.cpp
  custom-toolchain.cmake
  CMakeLists.txt
```

Can someone please help explain how I go about including the library into each container and how to include it correctly with CMake?

current working app implementation is as follows:
dockerfile for app1:

```
ARG IMAGE_TAG=2-bullseye
ARG TOOLCHAIN_ARCH=aarch64
ARG PKG_ARCH=arm64
ARG IMAGE_ARCH=linux/arm64

FROM torizon/debian-cross-toolchain-arm64:2-bullseye AS build

ARG PKG_ARCH
ARG TOOLCHAIN_ARCH

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    cmake \
    python-dev \
    gcc \
    make \
    gcc \
    binutils \
    build-essential \
    wget\
    libasound2-dev:arm64 \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /mypjsip
RUN mkdir out_libs

RUN wget https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/archive/2.10.tar.gz && tar -xvf 2.10.tar.gz
RUN cd pjproject-2.10/ && ./configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --disable-libwebrtc  && make dep && make && make DESTDIR=/mypjsip/out_libs install

COPY . app1_src
COPY $TOOLCHAIN_ARCH-toolchain.cmake app1_src/$TOOLCHAIN_ARCH-toolchain.cmake
RUN mkdir app1_src/build
RUN cd app1_src/build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./$TOOLCHAIN_ARCH-toolchain.cmake
RUN cd app1_src/build && make install

FROM --platform=linux/arm64 torizon/debian:$IMAGE_TAG
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    libasound2 \
    alsa-utils \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=build /mypjsip/pjproject-2.10/pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua* /usr/local/bin/pjsua
COPY --from=build /mypjsip/out_libs/* /
COPY --from=build /usr/bin/app1 /usr/bin/

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/app1" ]
```

cmake for app1:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(app1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(INC_DIR ./inc)
include_directories(${INC_DIR})

AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(src SOURCE_FILES)

add_executable(app1 ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(WARNINGS "\
-pedantic \
-pedantic-errors \
-Wextra \
-Wcast-align \
-Wcast-qual \
-Wdisabled-optimization \
-Werror \
-Wfloat-equal \
-Wformat=2 \
-Wformat-nonliteral \
-Wformat-security  \
-Wformat-y2k \
-Wimport \
-Winit-self \
-Winline \
-Winvalid-pch \
-Wmissing-field-initializers \
-Wmissing-format-attribute \
-Wmissing-include-dirs \
-Wmissing-noreturn \
-Wpacked \
-Wpointer-arith \
-Wredundant-decls \
-Wshadow \
-Wstack-protector \
-Wstrict-aliasing=2 \
-Wswitch-default \
-Wswitch-enum \
-Wunreachable-code \
-Wvariadic-macros \
-Wwrite-strings")


if ( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX )
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${WARNINGS} ")
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr)
install(TARGETS app1 DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about shared libraries in Docker.  The `libfoo.so.1` file needs to be in the image, in `/usr/lib` or another directory named in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, and you should run `ldconfig` after you install the library.  Do you have a partial implementation so far that you can share?

Comment: updated to include my dockerfile for app1 and cmakelists for app1

Comment: `From my understanding Docker does not play well with shared libraries so I'd need to static link.` Like, docker _exists_ so that it plays well with shared libraries. `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` You have to set it before the project, and anyway use `target_compile_options`. So you posted some files, but what is the actual problem you are facing? Does it "work"? If it doesn't, is there any message? Just build the libraries and executables, in docker, as you would on your own computer. You can create a short shell script for testing and run the same shell script in docker and on some host..

Comment: What I've posted is my current setup.  Now I need to understand HOW to get this to work how I need it.  How can I get my docker-compose + cmake to use the shared library? Again, I'm a novice at best w/ cmake and brand new to docker.

Comment: @UncleToby Just build the shared library in each container that needs it. Then use it. Just like you would do when using it on your own computer. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @UncleToby If all your images shares common requirements, you create your own docker image with all the c++ build tools and the shared library already on it, then just use that as the base for your other images.